# Simple Spring MVC Class Throws HTTP Status 406

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following simple Spring MVC test method to test using ResponseEntity.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>  home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    Map<String,String> returnMap = new HashMap<String,String>(2);
    returnMap.put("lang1", "Java");
    returnMap.put("lang2", "C++");
    ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> respEntity = new ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>>(returnMap,  HttpStatus.OK);
    return  respEntity;
}
```

ResponseEntity is created and in Eclipse debugger, I can see that body, header, and status code of the ResponseEntity object are all correct, but in the page I get the following error:

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating 
responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request 
"accept" headers ().
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you copy your spring config file here ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove produces JSON, or add responsebody annotation to your return type and changet the return type; having a ResponseEntity as return type and annotating the method as produces JSON is not goign to work. One or the other.

[Docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody)

Actually thinking about it, spring/jackson may actually convert the responsentity to json automatically. But either way you need responsebody to produce json.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem once it was because the following was missing from my `mvc-config.xml` file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```